# Calculating Over Time and Late Time payments in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need some help with a formula to automate my over-time and late time salary calculations. I get a report from our system which is in the following format:

"In Time" "Out Time" "Late" "Early" "OT"

All of these have values in the hh:mm:ss format however the cell is formatted as General.
The In Time has the time of the day I punch in.
The Out Time has the time of the day I punch out.
Late has the number of minutes I am late by from my check in time i.e. 10:00 not 10:15.
Early has the number of minutes I am early by.
OT has the number of hours and minutes I a work beyond my shift end time i.e. 6:00

I was hoping to get one column to tell me how much my salary would be deducted if I am late by x minutes. To give you an example, my day starts at 10:00 and I can come as late as 10:15 without any deductions. However for every minute I am late after that, I get a deduction which is calculated by the number of minutes I am late multiplied by my per minute salary ((((10000/30)/8)/60).

And in the second column, I was hoping to calculate how much additional salary I would get for my over time. For example, my shift ends at 6:00 and for every minute after 6:00 I am entitled to over time, which is calculated by the number of minutes I work over time multiples by my per minute over time rate (30/60).

Please let me know if you guys could help me with this. This could be used by almost anyone who wants to make sure their salary is calculated correctly.

Comment: You write "values in the hh:mm:ss format however the cell is formatted as General." That is odd unless the entry is really a Text string, and not a time.  Excel ordinarily stores times as fractions of a day.  But you may have to convert the data you are seeing into "real" times.  If the times that are being displayed as hh:mm:ss are really text strings, =ISTEXT(cell_ref) should return TRUE.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Ron. I tried this out and the value returned is True. What I really need help with, is the formula for the Late Deduction and Overtime Calculations. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Please edit your Original Post to provide examples of how your data is laid out, what you expect for results, what you have tried, and the results of what you have tried.  Also see HELP for how to ask a good question

Comment: Also, the results of your formula mean you will have to do some conversions to change your data from TEXT to numeric, which is how Excel stores times.  Possibly there is some character in the string that is forcing the TEXT conversion.  But you will need to examine your data carefully to determine why it is TEXT and not a Number.  Once your data is in the correct form, the math is trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "What I really need help with, is the formula for the Late Deduction and Overtime Calculations"

As I implied in my comments, the format of your data is all important.  Excel stores times as fractions of a day.  So 1 minute = 1/60/24

If you convert ÿour data to a normal Excel time, then the formulas for your Late Deductions and Overtime compensation would be as below.  Where **Late** is the number of minutes you are late (stored as an Excel Time); and **OT** is the number of overtime minutes.

If these values are stored as plain numbers, omit the **24*60** feature.  If these values are stored as Text, you need to change them to either regular numbers or fractions of a day.  Exactly how to change them depends on what is making them appear as text.

Late Deduction

```
=MAX(0,24*60*Late-15)*PerMinuteSalary
```

Overtime

```
=24*60*OT*PerMinuteOvertimeSalary
```

Comment: Thanks Ron, this really helped!